# Drop columns in a data.frame that do not contain a specific value?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a data.frame with 5 columns, 4 of the columns contain values from 0 to 99, only 1 column contains values from 0 to 100. Basically I want to create a logical function that drops whatever 4 columns don't contain a value of 100.

So hypothetically let's say column1, column2, column3 and column5 should be dropped because column4 is the only column that contains a value of 100.

Also, manually dropping the columns isn't an option because the column's values update daily through an automated framework. So a logical function would be perfect.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `colSums` :

```
df[, colSums(df == 100, na.rm = TRUE) > 0]

#    b   d
#1  10 100
#2  12  98
#3 100 100
#4   1   1
```

Or with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(~any(. == 100, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(89, 23, 25, 21),b = c(10, 12, 100, 1), 
                 c = c(10, 1, 3, 6), d = c(100, 98, 100, 1))
```

Comment: colSums worked great thank you! The dplyr method for some reason removed the wrong column

Comment: @srb633 Maybe that needs `na.rm` argument too. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah man I appreciate it, just one quick question due to my inexperience. When executing the original colSums line, it also removes the name of that column, leaving me with only the values? The datatype changes to "character", don't know if that has anything to do with it. I'll need the name to remain to identify the column that wasn't dropped, why would this be?

Comment: This can happen if you have only 1 column. Add `drop = FALSE`, `df[, colSums(df == 100, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, drop  =FALSE]`

Comment: Sweet that did it. Thanks again